# How to make Delphi's IDE scroll correctly?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

Recently I made a fresh install of Windows 10 and Delphi 2007.

On Windows mouse settings, I configured the vertical mouse wheel to scroll 5 lines.

Everything is working fine EXCEPT for the fact that when I'm in IDE editor, the mouse scroll wheel will behave in a unexpected way. It works OK when I scroll up, but when I scroll down, it will scroll very fast to the end of the file.

It may look like a trivial problem, but actually it is very annoying, because I use the mouse scroll wheel a lot to navigate in the editor, especially down, to find parts of the code, and instead of scrolling 5 lines, it scrolls a lot more, maybe 50...

The problem happens ONLY on the Delphi's IDE. If I open a file in Notepad, for instance, the scrolling works fine in both directions.

Is there any known bug related to this issue? Any fixes?

Comment: You might take a look at [this](http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.ide/trackpad-scroll-down-in-ide-goes-to-en/2028766), even if it is about Parallels, also https://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-mouse-scroll-speed-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What works for me is adding a boot flag to the VM configuration -> Boot order -> Advanced settings -> Boot flags. Add this line to this box:

devices.usb.mouse=0

Works for me with Delphi 14.2 on Windows 10 in Parallels 16.5.0

Comment: Wow, you made my day ! I've been plagued by this issue for months and now it's fixed !! A million thanks :-D

Comment: Looks like the recent update 17 of Parallels does not need this anymore. In fact, if you use this flag, the mouse will run VERY fast on Windows machine. I disabled this flag and fixed the mouse speed issue and the scrolling on Delphi worked as it should

Comment: @delphirules Just installed v17 and I can only confirm this, brilliant! Parallels seems have finally fixed it. But there is more: I also had `devices.pen=0` set to get my Wacom tablet behaving more or less normal, and that is also not needed anymore and very much improved. Now you have made my day!

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is evidently an issue with the mouse wheel which manifests itself when running under Parallels - see [here](http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.ide/trackpad-scroll-down-in-ide-goes-to-en/2028766)

> talking to the very helpful Parallels support, the problem is with 'smooth scrolling' implemented.  When this is turned off, the editor in Delphi works fine.  This apparently does happen with some programs and seems to be a Delphi problem rather than Parallels.

Also, for adjusting scroll-wheel sensitivity generally in Win10 see https://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-mouse-scroll-speed-windows

which says to go to Settings | Devices | Mouse & Touchpad and there are controls to set whether the mouse wheel scrolls a page at a time or multiple lines and another, a slider, to choose how many lines to scroll.

Comment: Recently i've upgraded to Delphi 10.4 and this issue is back, even setting Parallels correctly... any ideas please ?

Answer (score -1):

For me this helped:
steps: System > Advanced System Settings > Advanced > Performance > Settings > UNCHECK smooth-scroll list boxes

In German: Deaktivieren: Systemeigenschaften: "Optimierten Bildlauf für Listenfelder verwenden"